# Книги и учебные ресурсы по созданию ПО для дополнительных устройств для компьютера

Tags: книги, электроника

В общем хотелось бы научиться создавать самодельное электронное реле которое могло бы "общаться" с компьютером.

Также не нашёл книг по созданию драйверов на электронные изделия, с простейшими примерами.

В общем бы очень хотелось бы почитать книги в этом направлении

---

Есть книга ДМК Пресс "Встраиваемые системы на основе Linux ".

Она больше о линуксе, а хотелось бы, к примеру: *Создать лампу(220В) с таймером, которая при подключении по юсби к компьютеру распознавалась, имела бы свой протокол общения и понятное дело имела своё ПО"*

Comment: Пожалуйста, прочитайте описание метки "книги".

Comment: @PavelMayorov прочитал , ничего про программирование дополнительных устройств не обнаружил.

Comment: Это не отменяет того факта, что любой вопрос про книги - офтопик.